# NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; while launching Chrome using SoapUI

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, groovy, selenium-chromedriver, soapui

I'm trying to launch the selenium scripts from SoapUI 5.2.1 tool with the following launching script:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\ext\\chromedriver.exe")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.MyUrl.com")
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have kept the following selenium dependency file in **SoapUI/bin/ext** folder

**- chromedriver 2.36 

- selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar 

- selenium-chrome-driver-2.3.1.jar**

But I'm getting the following error message while running the script.

```
Tue May 22 15:51:47 IST 2018:ERROR:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at Script1.launchURL(Script1.groovy:49)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:20)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone help me to solve this issue as I'm not able to find correct solution in Google.

Thanks 
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

...implies that a *NoSuchMethodError* was raised when the os command `findExecutable()` tried to locate the executable as per your `System.setProperty() line`.

### Class **`NoSuchMethodError`**

[**`NoSuchMethodError`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) extends [**`IncompatibleClassChangeError`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html) and as per the *Java Docs* it is thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler and this error can only occur at *run time* if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed. *Incompatible class change* occurs due to change in definition of some class, on which the currently executing method depends.

### What went wrong?

You have created the *WebDriver* instance i.e. *driver* and casted it through *ChromeDriver()*. But the **SoapUI/bin/ext** sub-directory contains multiple defination from **selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar** and **selenium-chrome-driver-2.3.1.jar**.

### Solution

Perform the following steps :

- Remove **selenium-chrome-driver-2.3.1.jar** from **SoapUI/bin/ext** sub-directory.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Hi Debanjan, Thank you for the reply.. I will try these steps... :)

Answer (score 0):

Code to initialize the chromedriver is like the below code mentioned

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You need to set the correct dependency artifact id of selenium like

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

if you are using jar file then download the selenium jar file from here [Authentic link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)