# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

When I run my Java code in Eclipse it executes correctly but when I execute it via .bat file I get always same error:

Exception in `main` thread  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`

I have got imported `selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar` but anyways it fails.

My code of java is:

```
        File path = new File("C:/bin/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
        
        // Initiate PhantomJSDriver.
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
        //caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,phantomjsExeutableFilePath);
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"});
        Logger.getLogger(PhantomJSDriverService.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

And my bat file:

```
java -cp D:/JavaTestProject/bin/;D:/JavaTestProject/libs/* getInfo >>D:/logs/logGetInfo.txt 2>>D:/JavaTestProject/logs/logGetInfo.txt
```

I will really appreciate it if someone has got any idea of how can I solve this problem.

I have also tested the solution of this post but I have got same error:
[NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; while launching Chrome using SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465550/nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-os-commandline-findexecutableljava-lang)

Comment: I have also tested this post but I have got the same problem: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465550/nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-os-commandline-findexecutableljava-lang